# Local collection of Python packages: best way to import them?

Tags: python, module, package, local, software-distribution

I need to ship a *collection* of Python programs that use multiple *packages* stored in a local `Library` directory: the goal is to avoid having users install packages before using my programs (the packages are shipped in the `Library` directory). What is the best way of importing the packages contained in `Library`?

I tried three methods, but none of them appears perfect: is there a simpler and robust method? or is one of these methods the best one can do?

1. In the first method, the `Library` folder is simply added to the library path:

   ```
   import sys
   import os
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Library'))

   import package_from_Library
   ```

   The `Library` folder is put at the beginning so that the packages shipped with my programs have priority over the same modules installed by the user (this way I am sure that they have the correct version to work with my programs). This method also works when the `Library` folder is not in the current directory, which is good. However, this approach has drawbacks. Each and every one of my programs adds a copy of the same path to `sys.path`, which is a waste. In addition, all programs must contain the same three path-modifying lines, which goes against the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.
2. An improvement over the above problems consists in trying to add the `Library` path only once, by doing it in an imported module:

   ```
   # In module add_Library_path:
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'Library'))
   ```

   and then to use, in each of my programs:

   ```
   import add_Library_path
   import package_from_Library
   ```

   This way, thanks to the caching mechanism of CPython, the module `add_Library_path` is only run once, and the `Library` path is added only once to `sys.path`. However, a drawback of this approach is that `import add_Library_path` has an invisible side effect, and that the order of the imports matters: this makes the code less legible, and more fragile. Also, this forces my distribution of programs to inlude an `add_Library_path.py` program that users will not use.
3. Python *modules* from `Library` can also be imported by making it a package (empty `__init__.py` file stored inside), which allows one to do:

   ```
   from Library import module_from_Library
   ```

   However, this breaks for *packages* in `Library`, as they might do something like `from xlutils.filter import …`, which breaks because `xlutils` is not found in `sys.path`. So, this method works, but only when including modules in `Library`, not packages.

All these methods have some drawback.

Is there a better way of shipping programs with a collection of packages (that they use) stored in a local `Library` directory? or is one of the methods above (method 1?) the best one can do?

**PS**: In my case, all the packages from `Library` are pure Python packages, but a more general solution that works for any operating system is best.

**PPS**: The goal is that the user be able to use my programs without having to install anything (beyond copying the directory I ship them regularly), like in the examples above.

**PPPS**: More precisely, the goal is to have the flexibility of easily *updating* both my collection of programs and their associated third-party packages from `Library` by having my users do a *simple copy* of a directory containing my programs and the `Library` folder of "hidden" third-party packages. (I do frequent updates, so I prefer not forcing the users to update their Python distribution too.)

Comment: Any operating system!

Answer (score 2):

Messing around with `sys.path()` leads to pain... The [modern package template](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/modern-package-template) and [Distribute](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/index.html) contain a vast array of information and were in part set up to solve your problem.

What I would do is to set up setup.py to install all your packages to a specific site-packages location or if you could do it to the system's site-packages.  In the former case, the local site-packages would then be added to the PYTHONPATH of the system/user.  In the latter case, nothing needs to changes

You could use the batch file to set the python path as well. Or change the python executable to point to a shell script that contains a modified PYTHONPATH and then executes the python interpreter.  The latter of course, means that you have to have access to the user's machine, which you do not.  However, if your users only run scripts and do not import your own libraries, you *could* use your own wrapper for scripts:

```
#!/path/to/my/python
```

And the `/path/to/my/python` script would be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
PYTHONPATH=/whatever/lib/path:$PYTHONPATH /usr/bin/python $*
```

Comment: I added two PS two the question to make it clear that I don't want the user to have to do anything (like in the solutions I gave).

Comment: I unfortunately do not have access to the user's computer, as I "ship" them the programs (and, again, I am looking for a solution where they do not have to do anything).

Comment: +1 to the comment! Good question. :) I actually exceptionally ship Python too, with a few installed modules (for their platform); they "install" it by a simple copy. They access my programs through a batch file that sets the command path so that they used the shipped python when they run the python command. I would like to not touch this Python+base modules install too often, as it is bothersome for them to update it. Instead I want to ship some simple, additional packages "hidden" in a local `Library` folder, as needed by successive versions of my programs.

Comment: Good point. :) Yes, that would work for them. However—and I forgot to mention it—, a few users do not use the same method and do not have to run a batch file (me included). You made me update my question. :) May I suggest that you add a few of your comments to your answer? I would +1 it, because it's full of good ideas that could work for other people.

Comment: +1 to the question, because it can be useful to other users. In my case, it does not accomodate the need to run the distribution on different operating systems (there is a batch file for the Windows version, that sets paths and does the proper CD; there is no need for such a batch file for the Mac OS/Linux version).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at [path import hooks](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) which allow to modify the behaviour of python when searching for modules.

For example you could try to do something like kde's scriptengine does for python plugins[1].
It adds a special token to `sys.path`(like `"<plasmaXXXXXX>"` with `XXXXXX` being a random number just to avoid name collisions) and then when python try to import modules and can't find them in the other paths, it will call your importer which can deal with it.

A simpler alternative is to have a main script used as launcher which simply adds the path to `sys.path` and execute the target file(so that you can safely avoid putting the `sys.path.append(...)` line on every file).

Yet an other alternative, that works on python2.6+, would be to install the library under the per-user site-packages directory.

---

[1] You can find the source code under `/usr/share/kde4/apps/plasma_scriptengine_python` in a linux installation with kde.

Comment: The import hooks page is interesting, thanks! I added two PS to my question to make it more precise.