# Some way to create a cross-platform, self-contained, cloud-synchronized python library of modules for personal use?

Tags: python, cross-platform, packaging, python-module

I have migrated all my personal, pet projects to Dropbox, and this includes source code.

I enjoy using Python because I can switch to Windows or Linux machines, and I just to execute scripts and they work right away, no matter which OS or which specific machine I am using.

However, I would like to improve my workflow regarding REUSE of python functionality, which is overwhelmingly duplicated. Due to inept/lazy handling of imports, and the tendency to copy-paste my own module files to the same folder of every new script, not to say reimplementing the same micro-functionality over and over, I am seriously motivated to stop this workflow and adhere to strong reuse by using better-crafted, DRYed modules, and structured importing, ending up with higher-level, lean, problem-specific scripts.

It's important context that I've been "bitten" by the way .Net works in VisualStudio, you just go on `using` namespaces right away (well, sort of, provided the right references have been added, we know).

I have read quite a lot about *.pth files, **init**.py files, appending to `sys.path`, but that has been quite confusing to me.

My goals would be:

- Have a folder inside Dropbox (or GDrive, or whatever), with two subfolders: `Scripts` and `Modules`
- `Scripts` folder would contain only independent, single-file scripts, possibly inside subfolders in arbitrary levels of nesting, but they should not reference one another in any way, just reference the system-installed Python modules AND the modules packaged in `Scripts` folder;
- `Modules` folder should contain some hierarchical structure of folders and namespaces, with higher-level modules importing/reusing lower-level modules, and any of these modules using system-installed Python modules.

An additional desireable feature would be the ability to move some script elsewhere in the computer (copy it to desktop folder, for exemple) and with minimal or no modification it would still run, by still referencing modules inside `Dropbox/thatMagicFolder/Modules`.

A typical workflow that would reflect my needs:

1. I create a script in one machine, and make it run properly;
2. Then I go to another machine (also with Dropbox), install some lacking python modules (say, Numpy, or PIL), and then run the script I created in the other machine;
3. I update the script, adding some imports to more already-existing modules from `Modules` folder, and make it run properly. Ideally, the scripts would contain minimal if any boilerplate code;
4. I come back to the previous machine, wait for Dropbox to sync, and run the updated script right away!

I don't have a firm idea on how to achieve this, and my few previously mentioned tries (with `__init__` files and *.pth files) instead of simplify ended up making everything more complicated. But I still think this is something so natural, so obvious, that probably I am just missing something that is widely known by the initiated.

Any help is welcome, thanks for reading!

EDIT: an interesting, more detailed question on an almost identical problem (with no accepted answer) is this:

[Local collection of Python packages: best way to import them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15026634/401828)

Comment: I will try to help you (first let me get on my own pc). Your not looking to create an executable, right?

Comment: @enginefree no, usually open the files in some editor (I like to use Geany) and run them by pressing F5 (or the equivalent "Run" command). Thank you very much for your interest!

Comment: You probably want to add that `Modules` folder to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable, somewhere in your `.bashrc` (or Window Environment).